# PHP while loop find last row

Tags: php

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = 1");

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

<p>$i. <?php echo $row['comment'] ?></p>

<div class="border"></div>

$i++;
}
```

How could I do to not output `<div class="border"></div>` under the last comment?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = 1");
$number = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

   echo '<p>' . $i . $row['comment'] . '</p>';

   if ($i < $number)
   {
       echo '<div class="border"></div>';
   }

   $i ++;
}
```

Using WebDevHobo's suggestion.

Comment: You don't need the `$i`. Just use `if( --$number===0 )`.

Comment: With PDO : 

`$number = $req->rowCount();
while (...) {
   if (--$number != 0)
   {
   ...
   }
}`

Answer (score 8):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = 1");
$output = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $output[] = $row['comment'];
}
echo join('<div class="border"></div>', $output);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$number = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

This will tell you how many rows will be returned. Based on that, you can make sure that the last on does not have the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = 1");

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

$out_data[] = "<p>$i {$row['comment']} </p>";

$i++;
}

$divider = '<div class="border"></div>';
$output = implode ($divider, $out_data);

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rslt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = 1");

$i = 1;
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt)) {
  echo '<p>'. $i . ' '. $row['comment'] . '</p>';
  $i++;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt)){
    echo '<div class="border"></div>';
    echo '<p>'. $i . ' ' . $row['comment'] . '</p>';
    $i++;
  } // end while
} // end if
```

Avoids needing to know the number of rows.
Executes the if statement only once instead of each loop.
The HTML and php were kind of messy and inconsistent, so I just assumed the whole block was within php tags. Obviously, open and close the php tag as you see fit.

This is largely a style issue, but I decided that the variable name $sql was a bit misleading, as it is often and commonly used to hold the string of the sql statement to be executed, I therefore changed the variable name to $rslt.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer to this type of problem, and using Javascript because it's easy to throw in a console and play with:

```
var count = 0;
var foo = 3;
while( count < 3 ) {
    console.log("Header - " + count);
    console.log("Body - "+ count);
    console.log("Footer - " + count);
    count++;
}
```

This will print:

Header - 0
Body - 0
Footer - 0
Header - 1
Body - 1
Footer - 1
Header - 2
Body - 2
Footer - 2

The case being requested is basically saying "Print a footer on all but the last element."

If you consider the second loop iteration as simply a continuation of the first you can see how to do this without needing to find the total number of records - e.g. no need to do a second query for count. More succinctly: when you're stuck trying to figure out how to do something using a loop (or recursion) you should try actually writing out what your loop does, but without actually looping - e.g. copy and paste the loop block at least three times.

Rather than do that here, I'm just going to finish with the answer, and leave the derivation to the reader :~)

```
var count = 0;
var foo = 3;
while( count < 3 ) {
    if( count > 0 ) {
        console.log("Footer - " + (count - 1));
    }
    console.log("Header - " + count);
    console.log("Body - "+ count);
    count++;
}
```