# Check if this is the last row or not inside a while loop

Tags: php

I have this situation:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    if ($this_is_last_row == TRUE) {
        echo 'yes this is last row';
    } else {
        echo 'no, there is more rows';
    }
}
```

Is it possible to check each row on 'while' loop whether it's the last row or not, without knowing number of rows first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the last iteration in a while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436414/the-last-iteration-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: Will you provide some more information as what value you assign to the variable `this_is_last_row`.

Comment: @Nicolapps OP is asking about last row (from the database table) and not the last iteration of while loop.

Comment: well you can use `next()` and `current()` in order to move over the generator, but you can never be sure if there's more rows before you seek for next row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy:

```
$last = false;
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {

    $last = $row;

}
if ( $last !== false )
{
   // this is the last row:

}
```

There is no other way as stepping through the entire result set and hold the record. The remainder will be the last, or false if there are no records.
As usual, the result set does not know how many rows are in the back. `...fetch_all(...)` may end in a memory overflow when there are to many records.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247454/php-while-loop-find-last-row)

Looks like you can retrieve the number of rows and then just compare your current against that (maybe keep a count of your iteration and use that as the row number).

$number = mysql_num_rows($sql);

edit: in your case it looks like you'd want to use: `pg_num_rows`

Comment: I think this is the best answer.. Check the number of rows, increment $i for each row, if number is 10 rows, and $i = 10 then that's the final row.

Comment: OP would like to do this _without knowing number of rows first_.

Comment: On large record sets and with mysql functions, `..._num_rows` will not return the very number of records. see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-num-rows.html. As this is not a reliable way and depends on further settings which may have other backdrafts, I recommend to omit that.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, just improvise:

```
$curr = pg_fetch_row($result);
while ($curr) {
    $next = pg_fetch_row($result);
    if ($next) {
        echo 'no, there is more rows';
    } else {
        echo 'yes this is last row';
    }
    // use $curr anywhere _before_ this line
    $curr = $next;
}
```

Comment: This would miss a single row as the last row.

Comment: @AxelAmthor no it _will_ incluude the last row, even when there is one row in total.