# PHP - change last looping input type?

Tags: php, forms

I want to create a form submit, I've created a form using looping, but I need to change last loop input type from *number* to *select option*

there's some way how to do that with this code?

form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
    $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row2);
        ?>
        <label for="ik"><?php echo $nama_kriteria; ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik[]" id="ik" value=<?php echo $id_kriteria ?>>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nn" name="nn[]" min="1" max="100"
        <!-- I just want to change last loop for id="nn" -->
        placeholder="1 - 100">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

here's a result form:

[image: form]

any idea would be appreciate

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are wanting here, could you try to explain a little more for me please?

Comment: maybe by count the number of result and a condition to change if it's the last one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP while loop find last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247454/php-while-loop-find-last-row)

Comment: @LewisBrowne my bad for wrong comment sign, i want to change input type of last loop, and i've tried to find it on internet, but not lucky yet

Comment: @MacBooc thanks for the suggest, ill try it,

Comment: There's two answers with exactly that @RedRiver ;-)

Comment: @da39a3ee yep, i'm try it for now,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's the last row by counting. :)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
    $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
    $count = 1;
    $last = count($stmt2);

    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row2);
        ?>
        <label for="ik"><?php echo $nama_kriteria; ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik[]" id="ik" value=<?php echo $id_kriteria ?>>
        <?php if($last === $count): ?>
             // Add select input <--
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nn" name="nn[]" min="1" max="100" placeholder="1 - 100">
        <?php endif;
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

get the count for the total array and check last row

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
    $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
    $total_count = count($stmt2);
    $loop_cnt = 0; 
    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row2);
        $loop_cnt = $loop_cnt + 1;
        ?>
        <label for="ik"><?php echo $nama_kriteria; ?></label>
        <?php if($loop_cnt == $total_count): ?>
           //selec code here
       <?php else: ?>
           //input code here 
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```